# Neo4j rb finding connectivity between 2 nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I am using neo4j.rb in my rails application.

I already have two nodes n1 and n2 retrieved from the database.

Now i need to check if they have a path between them, i was thinking of using cypher queries using Neo4j::Session.query

But since i already have the two nodes i do not want to retrieve them again inside the query,(does it affect performance?) is there a way to do it?

I know i can use query1 = n1.query_as(:node1) and use it as the node identifier but how can i introduce n2 within the same query object so that i can check connectivity between them.

I want something equivalent to the query

```
RETURN 
  CASE 
    WHEN node1-[*..6]-node2  
    THEN 'Connected within 6 nodes'  
    ELSE 'Not connected within 6' 
  END
```

Where i already have node1 and node2.

Is a way to do this and also can this be done without using the CYPHER DSL?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but this is a great question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

```
n1.query_as(:n1).match_nodes(n2: n2).match('n1-[*1..6]-n2').count
```

If you want to avoid the Cypher DSL I think you can do that with associations.  As a starter example to traverse one level of relationships you can do this:

```
class N1Class
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_many :out, :test_association, type: :TEST_ASSOCIATION, model_class: :N2Class
end

n1.test_association.include?(n2)
```

That will test if they are directly connected via the `test_association` association.  You can even specify `false` for your `type` to ignore the direction and `false` for the `model_class` to ignore the target labels.

To get the variable length you can do this:

```
n1.test_association(nil, nil, rel_length: 1..6).include?(n2)
```

Comment: Nice i didn't know, you can do it without cypher DSL, is there a way we can get the shortest path between the two nodes also?

Comment: Yeah, i was also thinking the same thing, my cypher was not working, it was returning node urls i will post another question.

Comment: Good idea!  I don't think you can do that outside of the Cypher DSL yet, but I just created this issue to capture it: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/994